# When does a quadratic form being equal to zero implies the underlying matrix is equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n \in\mathbb{R}^m$ be vectors; and $M\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is a symmetric matrix. My question is as follows. Is there any condition $\mathcal{C}$ on $X_1,\dots,X_n$ such that, under $\mathcal{C}$, it holds: 
$$
X_i^T M X_i = 0 \iff M=0,
$$
and in the absence of $\mathcal{C}$, $X_i^T MX_i = 0\iff M=0$ fails, that is, there is a matrix $M\neq 0$ such that $X_i^T M X_i= 0$ but $M\neq 0$.

For instance, if ${\rm span}(X_iX_i^T)$ is the set of all ($m\times m$) symmetric matrices, then one can establish $X_i^T M X_i = 0\iff M=0$.

Comment: Ian, as an example take $X_i=e_i$ basis vectors. In this case, $X_i^T MX_i=0\Rightarrow M_{ii}=0$, but it does not say $M=0$. So, I don't think ${\rm span}(X_i)=\mathbb{R}^m$ is sufficient, no?

Comment: In the semidefinite case it is necessary and sufficient for $X_i$ to span $\mathbb{R}^m$. In the nonsymmetric case this is not sufficient (for a simple example, you might have a rotation), but even in the symmetric case it isn't sufficient. So effectively you need the maps $M \mapsto X_i^T M X_i$ to contain $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ linearly independent functionals on $\mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ which are symmetric in the sense that they are invariant under transposition. Which can probably be untangled into the same thing as your condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition that the matrices $X_iX_i^T$ span the symmetric matrices is both sufficient (as you indicated) and necessary.  That is, the condition that $X_iX_i^T$ span the symmetric matrices will work as your $\mathcal C$.

Note that the map $\langle A,B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB)$ forms an inner product over the space $\mathcal S$ of symmetric matrices.  Now, suppose that $\{X_iX_i^T\}$ fail to span $\mathcal S$.  It follows that there exists a non-zero symmetric matrix $M$ in the orthogonal complement $\operatorname{span}(\{X_iX_i^T\})^\perp$ (relative to $\mathcal S$).  Although $M$ is non-zero, we find that for any of our $X_i$ we have
$$
X_i^TMX_i = \operatorname{tr}(X_i^TMX_i) = \operatorname{tr}(MX_iX_i^T) = \langle M, X_iX_i^T \rangle = 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you Benjamin, good argument.